# Running mysqldump for daily backup from a separate Docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, cron

Is it a bad idea to create a separate `docker` container to run `mysqldump` using a cron job for daily backups?

Most people are using either the host machine's cron job or a separate cron container to run `mysqldump` from *inside* the container which is being backed up.

I would find it nicer to install `mysql` and execute `mysqldump` in the containder dedicated for backups. It would make the entire setup more segregated.

Are there any disadvantages or this approach?

Example of such a docker-compose-yml:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - ./mysql/mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql

  mysql-cron:
    image: mysql:latest
    build: .    
    environment:
      MYSQL_HOST: mysql
      MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: myuser
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: mypassword
      MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD: '1'
    volumes:
      - ./backup:/var/backup
```

The `Dockerfile` for mysql-cron would install 'cron' and setup crontab (not ready yet).

Comment: maybe replication instead?

Comment: Ref. [Creating database dumps](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql), you can `exec` into the container running the database and dump everything: `docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql` - you don't need to maintain your own image - you can run the dump on `cron` of the host (assuming linux) where the `docker` environment is running instead of building a custom image with `cron`.

Comment: Yes it's true that you can exec in a running container but the significant drawback of this approach is that you need to configure cron on the *host* machine (therefore it signifacantly reduces reusability across different Linux distros and also segregates the backup script from the actual db container). That's why I think that it's more elegant to set up the mysqldump backup also inside of the docker ecosystem. Are there any drawbacks on my solution above? Thanks!

Comment: @FlashThunder Yes replication is an interesting approach but it would take twice as much disk space in my case and also I'd need to monitor that the db replicas are in sync... I wanted to save this headache for myself. Other than that, yes, replication is a good approach.

Comment: I'm not aware of any linux / unix distribution that doesn't have `cron` - I'm lazy, wouldn't maintain an image unless I absolutely have too (is a drawback imo). For `docker` I'd use the host's `cron` and for `kubernetes` a [`CronJob`](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/) task. At the end of the day, if it works then I'd never say it's a "bad idea".

Comment: My point is that I'd like to keep all configuration *inside* of the docker files (like docker-compose.ym) and *configuring* cron on the host machines makes it impossible.

Comment: i understand OP, deploying would be much faster if the backup / cron process is also dockerized, and it would garantee that it would work in an identical way. (basically, I'm reexplaining the core idea behind docker...)

Answer (score 2):

Referring to the [official mysql](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql) image's documentation you can `docker exec` into the running container to dump the database to a path on the host: `docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql`

Assuming that you're using `docker` on Linux, chances are that you already have `cron` installed (you don't need to build and maintain your own image with `cron`).

You can add a `cron` job on the host where `docker` is running to `exec` into the container periodically and dump the database(s) (`crontab -e`) i.e. every day at 01:00 A.M.: `0 1 * * *    docker exec some-mysql sh -c 'exec mysqldump --all-databases -uroot -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD"' > /some/path/on/your/host/all-databases.sql`

**Note**: `cron` runs with a specific environment (e.g. ensure `docker` is in the `$PATH` available to `cron`, etc).